# Is it possible to increase Pgadmin4 speed?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have installed Pgadmin 4 on a Windows 10 x64 system with 16gb of ram.

The problem is: if I send a simple query on a PostgresSql14 server, like extracting some data on a 10 rows table and i make a **syntax error** ( for example mispelling an attribute or a comma) the **query** sometimes **runs forever** and i can't even kill it.
If i do the same error in the cmd this get caught in milliseconds.

I have tried to modify the values in postgresql.conf with this values:

`shared_buffers=4096MB`
`max_wal_size = 4GB`

Furthermore sometimes the query runs for many minutes even if it's correct and the data accessed are few.

Is this behaviour normal for PgAdmin4?
If not how to fix it?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format.

Comment: *"the query sometimes runs forever and i can't even kill it."* - i do curious how your query looked like. it can be [database related problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/257985) or your operating system doing funny stuff in the background. "my bike broke" is not a good question, its a statement.

Comment: try disabling windows defender's realtime protection and see if the performance improve or not. if yes, then your problem is os thing.